# How can I add count label in ggplot2 histogram when using breaks?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am trying to add count labels to a histogram created with ggplot. It works perfectly fine if I use default bins but if I use breaks to define the bars, the labels will be calculated and positioned as if I was using default bins. How can I choose the counts to be calculated from the breaks I assinged? I found some answers regarding using bins instead of breaks, but they all seem to have the issue that the first bar will not be from x=0 to x=20. It doesn't matter to me if the answer uses bins or breaks, but I want the first bar to have values between x=0 and x=20, and the rest of the bars be of same width. The data I am working with doesn't have negative values but it has values starting from 0 upwards.

This is how to reproduce the problem:

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- cars

ggplot(d, aes(x = dist)) + 
  geom_histogram(color="black", fill="gray", breaks=c(0,20,40,60,80,100,120)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,20,40,60,80,100,120)) +
  geom_text(stat='count', aes(label=..count..), vjust=-1)
```

And this is the outcome:

[image]

I have also used
`stat_count(bins=6, geom="text",aes(label=..count..))`
instead of geom_text(), but it gives the same result: it calculates the stats for 30 bins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Switch to `stat="bin"` in `geom_text` to compute the appropriate counts and use the same breaks as for `geom_histogram`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

d <- cars

breaks <- c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120)

ggplot(d, aes(x = dist)) +
  geom_histogram(color = "black", fill = "gray", breaks = breaks) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = breaks) +
  geom_text(
    stat = "bin", aes(label = after_stat(count)),
    vjust = -1, breaks = breaks
  )
```

[image]